# add html in jquery and use jquery on new html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am trying to add html using jquery and than i want to do actions according to the new added html.
Here is the example what i am trying to do..

This is my html

```
<div id='area'></div>
```

i use this jquery command to add html in this section

```
 $("#area").html('<p id="mynewid">my text</p>');
```

now i want to add text in p tag and i used this command

```
$("#mynewid").click(function() {

  $(this).html("my 2nd new text");

});
```

But it's not working...

Comment: What does 'it's not working' mean? Do you see any errors on the console? Does **anything** happen?

Comment: Oh Thanks for replying, Actually i want to ask that Am i using it right..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to learn about jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Change your code to;

```
$('area').on('click', '#mynewid', function(){
    $(this).html("my 2nd new text");
});
```

This is the best way to add event handlers to dynamically created content within the DOM.

The reason your code is not working is because I suspect that you have your `click()` handler already written before the new content is added to the `#area` `div`. This means that jQuery would attempt to attach the event handler to DOM elements that do not exist.

Comment: Thanks @Tim B James it's working now, actually if i add html using function e-g: function showmsg(){ $("area").html('<p id="mynewid">text</p>') } , then is it possible that i can use #mynewid as event out side the function..

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using needs to be executed once the DOM is ready. You can ensure this by including it in a `$(document).ready()` function like this:

```
<div id='area'></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#area").html('<p id="mynewid">my text</p>');
  $("#mynewid").click(function() {

    $(this).html("my 2nd new text");

  });

});
```

Add the appropriate HTML and this code works on my development box.